# Css animation visible on hovering

Tags: css, animation, visible, invisible

I've got a circle with an image underneath.

When I hover over the circle I want the circle to get bigger and be a mask of the image.
I have done that like this: (works in webkit)

```css
.clip {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(40px at center);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-clip-path 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: -webkit-clip-path 2s;
  }

.clip:hover {
        -webkit-clip-path: circle(75px at center);
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-wrapper">
  <div class="clip">
    <p>Workshops</p>
    <img name="workshops" alt="workshops" src="http://lorempixel.com/422/750" width="422" height="750" />
    <div class="workshops-container">
      <div class="workshop">
        <img name="workshop1" alt="workshop1" src="_img/ws1.png" width="placeholder" height="placeholder" />
        <header>
          <h1>Workshop 1</h1>
        </header>
        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="workshop">
        <img name="workshop2" alt="workshop2" src="_img/ws2.png" width="placeholder" height="placeholder" />
        <header>
          <h1>Workshop 2</h1>
        </header>
        <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do now, is the following:

I want, once I hover over the circle, the text that is inside, will be visible and a few other things (div workshops-container).
How do I start? I can't seem to find out how to make this work.

Comment: you probably need to use another element to play the mask role. it will be then crossbrowser. Else Javascript will be your friend but will still be avalaible only for latests webkit browsers.

Comment: the idea would be http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNMgxX